# XDebug and PHPUnit getting Code Coverage Wrong

Tags: php, testing, xdebug

I am using php 5.5.9 on Ubuntu 14.04.  I have upgraded Xdebug to the version that its Wizard recommends, that is version 2.2.6, and I have used apt-get to make sure my Ubuntu system is up to date.  The problem is, however, that my code coverage reports lines as executed when they are clearly not.

Here are the offending lines:

```
    if(!$filter->isValid()) {
        throw new Exception\InvalidInput($this->formatFilterErrors($filter));
    }
```

I know that the conditional code inside the if statement is not being executed, since the filtered data is always valid.  I can prove this by putting echo or die statements in the code block (above the throw statement) and they are never executed.

So why is code coverage telling me that the throw statement is being executed, numerous times?

Although I only have one example of incorrect reporting I really need to sort it out as a priority since I have a lot of testing to do on this application.  I could try upgraded PHP (but that has other consequences, of course).  Apart from that, my only option is to raise a but with the developer.

Have you come across this bug?  I have heard of others having problems with Xdebug on Ubuntu 14.04, but upgrading Xdebug has sorted their problems out.